# Can I install a 64bit python to raspbian os?

Tags: raspbian, python

I want to install a python 2.7 with 64 bit architecture is it possible?

Comment: Which OS are you using? Are you sure it's a 64-bit OS to begin with? (hint: official Raspbian isn't)

Comment: I want to see if i can have a 64bit python in raspbian os.

Comment: No, you can't have a 64-bit anything in a 32-bit system.

Answer (score 2):

1. **Both Python version  2.7 and version 3 have been pre-installed on Raspbian for quite some time.** A whole raft of Python GPIO libraries is preinstalled too !
2. You cannot run 64-bit software on 32-bit Operating Systems. All releases of Raspbian run the Pi3 in 32-bit mode
   only.
3. Furthermore , a download page advertising 64-bit downloads is very likely offering x86_64 binaries which are useless for ARM computers like the Pi.